# How do I assign a shortcut to a QPushButton?

Tags: c++, qt, qpushbutton

The documentation on assigning a shortcut to a QPushButton is as follows:

---

A shortcut key can be specified by preceding the preferred character with an ampersand in the text. For example:

```
QPushButton *button = new QPushButton("&Download", this);
```

In this example the shortcut is Alt+D.

---

What do I do if I don't want an `Alt+[A-Z]` shortcut? For example, in my case I want my button to be fired when the `TAB` button is pressed.  How can I achieve this effect?

Answer (score 17):

You can use [`setShortcut`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#shortcut-prop) method, eg:

```
pushButton->setShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt::Key_Tab));
```

It will fire then slots assigned to the `clicked()` signal

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [QShortcut](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qshortcut.html). Another tip: Qt signal / slots mechanism allows you to connect a signal to a signal.

Answer (score 0):

You can overload QWidget::keyPressEvent and trigger your button click directly or through previously specially connected signal

```
void MainWindow::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent * pEvent)
{
    if (Qt::Key_Tab == pEvent->key())
    {
        ui->button->click();
    }

    QMainWindow::keyPressEvent(pEvent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define the key, the target object and it's relevant slot in the constructor of `QShortcut` :

```
QShortcut * shortcut = new QShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt::Key_Tab),button,SLOT(click()));
shortcut->setAutoRepeat(false);
```